ARM based microprocessor IC number, what is the exact model of microprocessor?
It is a ARM based microprocessor with 48 pin count and most probably 32-bit

and one more detail which may help is that another single EEPROM IC has been used alongside? What is the tentative model of microprocessor?

You need to remove that glue residue, it's covering up the model number. Try isopropyl alcohol and a cotton swab.

Well, the package says GigaDevices and the top marking is xx32Fxx3. So probably a STM32F103 clone made by GigaDevices. If you take a photo with readable markings, it will be easy to tell the exact one.

For more dependable answer, you can post to ARM forum. Since, they are the manufacturer of ARM microcontrollers, they are most likely to provide the right answer. If you're interested in knowing more about new ARM and other ICs, you can see here: https://www.theengineeringprojects.com/2023/08/top-embedded-ics-to-learn-in-2023.html

Looks like GD32F403RET6 as far as I can tell. According to the datasheet it could also be GD32F303RET6 or GD32F103RET6.
